# PHP issue: using if statement

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

Hello I have a problem in one of my php projects. The problem states that I need to provide the top students for each year of classes as well as the best overall student. However i am having trouble with the if statments; I am unable to post the name of each student where the name should be it displays their score for the year.

pic of database:

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img843/9674/7r2t.png

here is my code:

```
<body>
    <form>
        <?php
        $username = "amar";
        $password = "amar";
        $hostname = "localhost";
        $database = "study";
        $set = 100;
        $met = 0;

        $mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database)
                or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

        $query = "select Name, year_1, year_2, year_3, year_4, Final, Final_Grade  from toppers";
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

        if (!$result) {
            $message = 'Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error() . "\n";
            $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
            die($message);
        }

        echo "<table border=1 cellpadding=5>";
        echo "<tr><td>Student Name</td>";
        echo "<td>2011</td>";
        echo "<td>2012</td>";
        echo "<td>2013</td>";
        echo "<td>2014</td>";
        echo "<td>Final Exam</td>";
        echo "<td>Grade</td></tr>";




        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            $grader = "$_POST[result]";
            $x = $row['year_1'] + $row['year_2'] + $row['year_3'] + $row['year_4'] +     $row['Final'];
            $grader = $x / 5;
            $row[Final_Grade] = $grader;

               if ($grader <= 100 and $grader >= 89) {
                $grade = "A";
            } elseif ($grader <= 90 and $grader >= 79) {
                $grade = "B";
            } elseif ($grader <= 80 and $grader >= 69) {
                $grade = "C";
            } elseif ($grader <= 70 and $grader >= 59) {
                $grade = "D";
            } else {
                $grade = "F";
            }

            if ('$row[Final]' > $set) {
                $year1 = $grade;
                $year2011 = $row;
            }
            if ('$row[Final]' < $set) {
                $year2 = $grade;
                $year2012 = $row;
            }
            if ('$row[Final]' < $set) {
                $year3 = $grade;
                $year2013 = $row;
            }
            if ('$row[Final]' < $set) {
                $year4 = $grade;
                $year2014 = $row;
            }
            if ('$row[Final]' < $set) {
                $final = $grade;
                $finalscore = $row;
            }
            if ('$row[Final]' < $set) {
                $overall = $grade;
                $overall = $row;
            }

            echo "<tr><td>";
            echo "$row[Name]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$row[year_1]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$row[year_2]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$row[year_3]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$row[year_4]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$row[Final]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$grade";
            echo "</td></tr>";
        }           

        echo "<tr><td colspan=7>Topper for 2011: </td></tr>";
            echo "$year2011[Name]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$year2011[year_1]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$year2011[year_2]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$year2011[year_3]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$year2011[year_4]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$year2011[Final]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$grade";
            echo "</td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td colspan=7>Topper for 2012: </td></tr>";
            echo "$year2012[Name]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$year2012[year_1]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$year2012[year_2]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$year2012[year_3]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$year2012[year_4]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$year2012[Final]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$grade";
            echo "</td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td colspan=7>Topper for 2013: </td></tr>";
            echo "$year2013[Name]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$year2013[year_1]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$year2013[year_2]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$year2013[year_3]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$year2013[year_4]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$year2013[Final]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$grade";
            echo "</td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td colspan=7>Topper for 2014: </td></tr>";
            echo "$finalscore[Name]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$finalscore[year_1]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$finalscore[year_2]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$finalscore[year_3]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$finalscore[year_4]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$finalscore[Final]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$grade";
            echo "</td></tr>";

        echo "<tr><td colspan=7>Topper overall: </td></tr>";
            echo "$overall[Name]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$overall[year_1]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$overall[year_2]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$overall[year_3]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$overall[year_4]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$overall[Final]"; 
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$grade";
            echo "</td></tr>";
        echo "</table>";
```

Comment: An expression like `'$row[Final]'` is tolerated by PHP but it will generate some notices. Write it like: `$row['Final']`. Similarly `echo "$row[Name]";` becomes `echo $row["Name"];`

Comment: also `$grader = "$_POST[result]";` should be `$grader = $_POST['result'];`

Comment: @Doge `'$row[Final]'` will be that exact string because of single quotes. No notices. However, it is still wrong and should be `$row['Final']`.

Answer (score 2):

Everything in single quotes in PHP gets interpreted literally as a string. When you do `'$row[Final]'` PHP interprets that as "dollar sign, open bracket, the word 'Final', close bracket."

In order to have PHP interpret what you're saying as a reference to a variable, you have to reference only your index as a string, leaving the rest outside your quotes.

`$row["Final"];` tells PHP, "check the variable `$row` and see what's stored at it's index represented by the string `Final`."

[PHP: Strings - Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to store the highest result for each group you want to display later (ie, highest for each year), rather than just one single highest store in $set.

Not 100% sure on what you want, but to give you an idea something like this:-

```
<body>
    <form>
        <?php
        $username = "amar";
        $password = "amar";
        $hostname = "localhost";
        $database = "study";
        $set = array('2011'=>0, '2012'=>0, '2013'=>0, '2014'=>0, 'final'=>0, 'Final_Grade'=>0);

        $mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database)
                or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

        $query = "select Name, year_1, year_2, year_3, year_4, Final, Final_Grade  from toppers";
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

        if (!$result) {
            $message = 'Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error() . "\n";
            $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
            die($message);
        }

        echo "<table border=1 cellpadding=5>";
        echo "<tr><td>Student Name</td>";
        echo "<td>2011</td>";
        echo "<td>2012</td>";
        echo "<td>2013</td>";
        echo "<td>2014</td>";
        echo "<td>Final Exam</td>";
        echo "<td>Grade</td></tr>";

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
        {

            $grader = $_POST['result'];
            $x = $row['year_1'] + $row['year_2'] + $row['year_3'] + $row['year_4'] + $row['Final'];
            $grader = $x / 5;
            $row['Final_Grade'] = $grader;

            switch (true)
            {
                case ($grader <= 100 and $grader >= 89) :
                    $grade = "A";
                    break;
                case ($grader <= 90 and $grader >= 79) :
                    $grade = "B";
                    break;
                case ($grader <= 80 and $grader >= 69) :
                    $grade = "C";
                    break;
                case ($grader <= 70 and $grader >= 59) :
                    $grade = "D";
                    break;
                default :
                    $grade = "F";
                    break;
            }

            if ($row['Final'] > $set['2011']) 
            {
                $year2011 = $row;
                $set['2011'] = $row['Final'];
            }
            if ($row['Final'] < $set['2012']) 
            {
                $year2011 = $row;
                $set['2011'] = $row['Final'];
            }
            if ($row['Final'] < $set['2013']) 
            {
                $year2011 = $row;
                $set['2011'] = $row['Final'];
            }
            if ($row['Final'] < $set['2014']) 
            {
                $year2011 = $row;
                $set['2011'] = $row['Final'];
            }
            if ($row['Final'] < $set['final']) 
            {
                $finalscore = $row;
                $set['final'] = $row['Final'];
            }
            if ($row['Final_Grade'] < $set['Final_Grade']) 
            {
                $overall = $row;
                $set['Final_Grade'] = $row['Final_Grade'];
            }

            echo "<tr><td>";
            echo "$row[Name]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$row[year_1]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$row[year_2]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$row[year_3]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$row[year_4]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$row[Final]";
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo "$grade";
            echo "</td></tr>";
        }           

        echo "<tr><td colspan=7>Topper for 2011: </td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>".implode("</td><td>", $year2011)."</td></tr>";

        echo "<tr><td colspan=7>Topper for 2012: </td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>".implode("</td><td>", $year2012)."</td></tr>";

        echo "<tr><td colspan=7>Topper for 2013: </td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>".implode("</td><td>", $year2013)."</td></tr>";

        echo "<tr><td colspan=7>Topper for 2014: </td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>".implode("</td><td>", $year2014)."</td></tr>";

        echo "<tr><td colspan=7>Topper overall: </td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>".implode("</td><td>", $overall)."</td></tr>";

        echo "</table>";
```